# Why does SeedRandom with same seed used twice produce such different results?

Tags: random

I have occasionally used `RandomSeed[100]` twice in the code and noticed behaviour that I don't understand.

Consider:

```
Clear[X, tmp, tmp1]
SeedRandom[100];
X = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{-1, 1}], 1000];
tmp = RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[#]] & /@ LogisticSigmoid[X];

SeedRandom[100]; 
tmp1 = RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[#]] & /@ LogisticSigmoid[X];
```

Then if we plot both responses, they are very different - `tmp` produces correct (blue) result, but `tmp1` (orange) produces strange outcome:

```
ListPlot[{
  Thread[{X, tmp}], 
  Thread[{X, tmp1}]
  }, PlotMarkers -> {"-", "+"}]
```

[image]

Why is it so?

**EDIT** As @JimB correctly admits, it appears that `tmp1` produces 0's whenever X is negative and 1's whenever X is positive. And it appears to be happening *only* when *the same seed* is used, i.e. 100 in the example.

Comment: You're not executing the same statements after setting the seed.  You need a `X1 = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{-1, 1}], 1000];` right before defining `tmp1`.  And the definition of `tmp1` also needs `X` changed to `X1`.

Comment: @JimB, I know that, but why this other statement generates such picture (I would expect that it would just made another version of distribution but it simply set all 1s for positive and all 0s for negative values without randomness as in the `tmp` case given similar X.

Comment: I see now.  So it appears that `tmp1` produces 0's whenever `X` is negative and 1's whenever `X` is positive.  I think a table showing that would make the issue clearer.  And it appears to be happening only when the same seed is used.  Maybe this is exactly what you were stating but it wasn't clear to me.

Comment: It looks like [`RandomVariate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomVariate) on different distributions use the same underlying random number generator. In other words, when using the same seed, random numbers generated from different distributions will be correlated. I think it's worth reporting to support, since if nothing else, the documentation ought to list this as a possible issue.

Comment: @CarlWoll, thank you. I've sent them a message. I'll come back if get something from support team.

Comment: @CarlWoll Erm. I would rather see a problem if two successive calls to `RandomVariate` for distinct distributions would reseed with the same seed. _Then_ their output would be dependent on each other. A good random number generator should produce pseudorandom numbers that are nearly stochastically independent.

Comment: @CarlWoll So if one call to `RandomVariate` uses one part of the random sequence generated by the random number generator and the call uses another, nonoverlapping part of that sequence (as it appears to happen), then the outcome is not (essentially) more dependent than the distributions themselves.